# Мобильная верстка выпадает из размеров экрана

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Столкнулся с такой пролемой при мобильной адаптации верстки.
Когда я захожу в режим разработчика в хроме и выбираю мобильную версию показа страницы, то верстка уходит за пределы заданных максимальных размеров. Пример на скрине:
[image: Вот так выглядит верстка]

Но после того, как я начинаю выбирать несколько раз различные версии мобильных телефонов, то все становится нормально и начинает правильно отображаться на всех версия мобильных телефонов.
Help me, please!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормально. После перехода в разработчик в хроме (да и других тоже) и выбора мобильной версии показа страницы, следует перегрузить страницу (F5 или Ctrl+F5) и пару раз переключить вид на разных устройствах - это эмуляция, и не все срабатывает сразу.

Следует учитывать, что не все моменты на реальных устройствах отрабатывают (или совсем так отрабатывают) в разработчиках.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!